# Creating a property inside of an object that can be continuously used

Tags: javascript

I'm the type of person who loves to do a lot of projects especially if it involves only JavaScript since that is my strong point.

I thought of a little fun idea. Writing little pieces of CSS with JavaScript. These CSS pieces could then be used in a Blob or implemented into the webpage some other way.

`Most of the time, I do projects just for FUN and for build up in experience.`

Let's get more of a feel for what we are working with. One of these JavaScript stylesheets could look like this:

```
var sheet = {
    "h1": {
        "font-size": "24px",
            "color": "blue",
        children: {
            "a": {
                "font-size": "15px"
            }
        }
    },
    "a": {
        color: "red"
    }
};
```

This would return:

`h1{font-size:24px;color:blue}h1 a{font-size:15px}a{color:red}`

Note the `children` propert in the `h1` element.

This is my way of nesting, making the `h1 a`.

My question however is, how could I make a continuous nesting so I could end up with something like:

"h1 div span a"

Meaning that each nested child will need be able to use the `children` property.

The script I have so far is below (belongs with the variable `sheet`).

```
var to = "";
for (var el in sheet) {
    var props = [];
    for (var prop in sheet[el]) {
        if(prop != "children") {
            props.push(prop + ":" + sheet[el][prop]);
        }
    }
    to += el + "{" + props.join(";") + "}";
    //----
    if (sheet[el].children) {
        for (var el2 in sheet[el].children) {
            var props = [];
            for (var prop in sheet[el].children[el2]) {
                props.push(prop + ":" + sheet[el].children[el2][prop]);
            }
            to += el + " " + el2 + "{" + props.join(";") + "}"
        }
    }
    //----
}
```

The sections in between the comments is the code I use for the 1 time nesting.

I'm not sure how difficult this would be to add. But I understand that it probable wouldn't be easy.

My full example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/2tfnz/1

Comment: Note that `h1 a` does not target **children** `<a>` elements of `<h1>`. It targets **descendant** `<a>` elements. `h1 > a` will target **children** `<a>` elements

Comment: I also always do project for fun. Get your idea and trying the best.

Comment: @silentboy I totally agree. Some projects can really get your brain thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pretty easily make your code recursive:

```
function buildCSS(stub, node){
    var to = "";
    for (var el in node) {
        var rule = stub + " " + el;
        var props = [];
        for (var prop in node[el]) {          
            if(prop != "children") {
                props.push(prop + ":" + node[el][prop]);
            }
        }
        to += rule + "{" + props.join(";") + "}";
        if (node[el].children) {
            to += buildCSS(rule, node[el].children);
        }
    }

    return to;
}

var to = buildCSS("", sheet);
```

This can definitely be cleaned up, but it illustrates the idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/2tfnz/3/

---

You might also consider a tweak to your object structure to make the code a bit cleaner:

```
var sheet = {
    "h1": {
        rules: {
            "font-size": "24px",
            "color": "blue"
        },
        children: {
            "a": {
                rules: {
                    "font-size": "15px"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "a": {
        rules: {
            color: "red"
        }
    }
};
```

In this way, you wouldn't need to distinguish between properties named `children` and those which aren't.

Comment: Hey, you steal my idea. You must be a theif. However +1 cause you are so much speady than me.

Comment: Haha, Thanks for such a fast answer :D

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/2tfnz/6/

Put the code in a method so it can recursively call itself when it finds children. This one allows for both `children` and `descendant` properties and outputs nicely formatted CSS.

```
var sheet = {
    "h1": {
        "font-size": "24px",
        "color": "blue",
        children: {
            "a": {
                "font-size": "15px",
                descendants: {
                    "span": {
                        "font-weight": "bold"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "a": {
        color: "red"
    }
};

function toCSS(obj, pre) {
    var str = '', pre = pre || '';

    for (var selector in obj) {
        str += pre + selector + ' {\n';

        var rules = obj[selector];
        for (var ruleKey in rules) {
            if (['descendants', 'children'].indexOf(ruleKey) > -1) continue;
            str += '  ' + ruleKey + ': ' + rules[ruleKey] + ';\n';
        }

        str += '}\n\n';

        if ('descendants' in rules) str += toCSS(rules.descendants, pre + selector + ' ');
        if ('children' in rules) str += toCSS(rules.children, pre + selector + ' > ');
    }

    return str;
}


console.log(toCSS(sheet));
```

Answer (score 0):

I like all of you guy's code. However, I told the idea of making my code recursive.

So I've made:

```
        var to = "";
        for (var el in sheet) {
            var props = [];
            var nest = [el];
            var nestLookUp = {
                    "children": ">", 
                    "desendents": ""
            };
            var nests = /children|desendents/;
            var addNest = function (shh) {
                for (var found in nestLookUp) {
                    if (shh.hasOwnProperty(found)) {
                        for (var el2 in shh[found]) {
                            var props = [];
                            nest.push(nestLookUp[found]);
                            nest.push(el2);
                            for (var prop in shh[found][el2]) {
                                if (!prop.match(nests)) {
                                    props.push(prop + ":" + shh[found][el2][prop]);
                                }
                            }
                            if (props.length > 0) {
                                to += nest.join(" ").replace(/\s{2}/, " ") + "{" + props.join(";") + "}";
                            }
                            addNest(shh[found][el2]);
                            nest.pop();
                            nest.pop();
                        };
                    }
                }
            };
            for (var prop in sheet[el]) {
                if (prop != "children") {
                    props.push(prop + ":" + sheet[el][prop]);
                }
            }
            to += el + "{" + props.join(";") + "}";
            addNest(sheet[el]);
        }
```

@Trevor - Your Idea with the `descendants`, is a good one :)

My code is a little longer than Trevors but personally more manageable. (39 lines his is 20)

I usually like making my own code because I usually understand how the code works.

Ha, I was a little confused looking at you guys code.

Comment: Yours doesn't quite work. Look at http://jsfiddle.net/2tfnz/7/. It's generating `h1 > a > span > .crazy` when it should do `h1 > .crazy`. You need keep track of ancestors by passing them in your recursive call. Using shared variables like you're doing is very messy.